# Paginação e Order BY

Tags: wordpress, paginação, link, ascii

Tenho notado que alguns sites em wordpress usam nos links o seguinte codigo

?orderby=title&order=asc

Poderiam me explica quais as variações desse codigo?

Por exemplo, seria possivel ordena artigos por letra da seguinte maneira.

?orderby=title&order=asc letra A : mostra artigos com letra A

?orderby=title&order=asc numero de posts : mostra 20 artigos

Comment: chegou a ver a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Essas "variações" que você vê são os parâmetros da [WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters). No link você pode ver todas as (muitas) possíveis combinações que podem ser feitas. Respondendo às suas perguntas em particular:

> Mostrar artigos com a letra A

Artigos que contém a letra A, em *qualquer* ponto do artigo? Artigos cujo título *inicia* com a letra A?

Supondo que seja a última, acredito que você tenha que fazer alguma espécie de filtro após a consulta. Não sei se isso é possível apenas usando os parâmetros da query. Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 //retorna todos os posts da base
);

query_posts($args);

if (have_posts()) { 

    $letra = 'A';

    while (have_posts()){
        the_post();
        $letraInicial = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));
        if ($letraInicial == $letra) {
            // coisas do loop, como the_title() e etc
        }
    }
}
```

Esse código está longe de ser ótimo, mas acredito que funcione como prova de conceito. Basicamente, ele busca todos os posts da sua base, e compara a primeira letra de cada um deles com uma letra que você estabelece previamente. Para consultas mais complexas ou até mais performáticas, você pode brincar com a [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

> Mostrar 20 artigos

Existe um parâmetro próprio para isso:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 20 //retorna o número de posts desejados
);
```

Em formato de query string:

```
/?orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=20
```